# Python bucle for

Tags: python, bucle-for

Me piden escribir un programa que pida al usuario un número entero positivo y muestre por pantalla todos los números impares desde 1 hasta ese número separados por comas.

Mi código es:

```py
num=int(input('Ingrese un número entero positivo\n'))

for i in range (1,(num+1)):
    if i%2==1:
        print(f'{i},',end='')
```

Si en el `input` escribo 10 imprime 1,3,5,7,9,

La coma después del 9 sobra pero no sé cómo quitarla

Answer (score 4):

Tienes muchas formas:

- Detectar que se trata del último número y no imprimir la coma en ese caso.
- Más fácil, poner la coma delante y omitirla en el primer número (es más fácil porque puedes tener un booleano que indique si ya has pasado por el primer número)
- Crear una lista con los números (en forma de cadenas), en vez de imprimirlos, y al final imprimir la lista usando `.join()`.

Voy a mostrar los dos últimos casos

### Imprimir coma delante

```
num=int(input('Ingrese un número entero positivo\n'))
es_primero = True
for i in range (1,(num+1)):
    if i%2==1:
      if es_primero:
         print(f'{i}',end='')
         es_primero = False
      else:
         print(f',{i}', end='')
```

### Usando una lista

```
num=int(input('Ingrese un número entero positivo\n'))

resultado = []
for i in range (1,(num+1)):
    if i%2==1:
        resultado.append(str(i))

# Una vez terminamos, mostramos el resultado
print(",".join(resultado))
```

**Otra forma**, sugerida por @MauricioContreras.

A `print()` se le pueden pasar muchos parámetros, por ejemplo: `print(1, 8, 5, 2)`, y normalmente los imprimirá separados por espacios (en este ejemplo sacaría `1 8 5 2`). Con el parámetro adicional `sep=` podemos especificarle otro separador distinto del espacio, por lo que podríamos poner `sep=','` para que separe por comas.

El problema es ¿cómo pasarle los elementos que tenemos en `result` como parámetros separados? Si hacemos `print(result, sep=',')` no obtendremos el resultado buscado, pues `print()` está recibiendo un solo parámetro (de tipo lista), en lugar de varios números.

Para estos casos Python tiene el operador de *desempaquetado* `*`. Pondríamos:

```
print(*resultado, sep=',')
```

El `*` delante de una lista la *desempaqueta*, es decir pasa cada uno de sus elementos como un parámetro separado. Ahora sí `print()` estará recibiendo varios parámetros (los números) e imprimirá correctamente el resultado.

Además esto tiene la ventaja sobre `",".join(resultado)` de que `.join()` necesita que todos los elementos de la lista a juntar sean de tipo cadena (por eso en el `.append()` usé `str()` a la hora de meterlos), mientras que `print(*resultado)` admite que los elementos de la lista sean de cualquier tipo.

## Bonus: Comprensiones de listas

Cuando usas un bucle for para crear una lista (como en la segunda solución) puedes usar si prefieres la sintaxis de *compresión de listas*. Es una sintaxis alternativa para generar toda una lista en una sola línea.

La sintaxis es un poco confusa, porque aparece dentro la palabra `for` y puede aparecer también la palabra `if` (en este caso la necesitamos), pero no se trata de una sentencia for ni de una sentencia condicional, sino de una *expresión*, lo que implica que es algo que puede aparecer dentro de una asignación o como parámetro de una función.

En este caso la comprensión de lista sería:

```
[ x for x in range(1, num+1) if x%2==1 ]
```

Que vendría a leerse casi casi traduciéndolo directamente al español en el mismo orden en que se lee, como si fuera una definición matemática del conjunto de los impares menores de 10. La lectura sería esta:

> El conjunto está formado por:
>
> El valor x, para toda x en el rango de 1 a 10, tal que x%2 es igual a 1

El resultado es una lista directamente, y puede ser asignado a una variable:

```
resultado = [ x for x in range(1, num+1) if x%2==1 ]
```

O ni siquiera tienes por qué asignarlo a ninguna variable, puedes pasarlo directamente como parámetro de `print()`, y tu programa queda reducido a dos líneas:

```
num=int(input('Ingrese un número entero positivo\n'))
print(*[x for x in range(1,(num+1)) if x%2], sep=",")
```

Comment: O poner todos los impares en una lista y una sola llamada a `print` pasando la lista y usando el parámetro `sep=','`. O me equivoco?

Comment: Funcionaría si expandes la lista con el asterisco: `print(*lista, sep=',')`, si no te va a imprimir también los [ ] que delimitan la lista (y además `sep=','`sería superfluo en ese caso)

Comment: Pues gracias por la aclaración. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos.  Al final quedó
print(*resultado,sep=',')
y salieron los números como yo quería

Comment: @Neo Si no conoces la sintaxis de comprensión de listas, échale un vistazo a la ampliación que he añadido en la respuesta.

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias, el tema está muy interesante, de hecho hice algunos ejercicios tomando como base listas que estaban construidas de la forma tradicional y las "traduje" a la sintaxis de la comprensión de listas y me salió muy bien. Otra historia será cuando  tenga que crearlas yo mismo sin una guía. De cualquier forma llevo apenas unos días "estudiando" Python y he avanzado bastante, comparado con los meses que estuve rayándome la cabeza con js sin llegar a ningún lado. De nuevo gracias